# I want to perform System.exit[0] via return keyword in the game written in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a tic-tac-toe game , where i make 9 buttons and then mark the button `x` or `o` by turn and change the color for the mark.

I also have a `checkIsWinner` function that checks the winning combinations. If the combination is a winner then i use a variable and check it true if there is a combination, i use this variable so that i can perform `System.exit(0)`, to exit from the program. But this variable trick doesn't seem to work.

Please help. I want to stop the program when there is a winner.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var table = [];
  var blocks = 9;
  var player1, player2, boardId;
  var elem, Id;
  var chance = 1;
  var tie = 10;
  var isWinner = false;
  var checkTie = false;
  var buttonKey;
  var outputArray = [];
  var array1, array2, array3, array4, array5, array6, array7, array8,
    array9, array10, array11, array12;
  var array13, array14, array15, array16, array17, array0;
  winningCombinations = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 9],
    [1, 5, 9],
    [3, 5, 7]
  ];

  $(document).ready(function() {

    buttonId = 1;

    for (var index = 0; index < blocks; index++) {
      buttonKey = document.createElement("button");

      if ((index == 3 || index == 6)) {
        lineBreak = document.createElement('br');
        document.body.appendChild(lineBreak);
      }

      buttonKey.innerHTML = " + ";
      buttonKey.id = buttonId;
      buttonKey.setAttribute("value", buttonId);
      buttonKey.setAttribute("text", buttonId);
      // button.setAttribute("onclick",selectColor());
      buttonKey.style.fontFamily = "Times New Roman";
      buttonKey.style.backgroundSize = "50px";
      buttonKey.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0";
      buttonKey.style.fontSize = "25px";
      buttonKey.style.marginBottom = "10px";
      buttonKey.style.marginLeft = "5px";
      buttonKey.style.marginRight = "5px";
      document.body.appendChild(buttonKey);
      buttonId++;



      buttonKey.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

        selectMark(event, event.srcElement);
        checkIsWinner();
        if (isWinner == true || checkTie == true) {
          return false;
        }
      });
    }

  });

  function selectMark(currentObject, currentType) {

    if (chance % 2 != 0) {
      player1 = 'x';
      outputArray.push([currentType.id, player1]);
      document.getElementById(currentType.id).innerHTML = player1;
      document.getElementById(currentType.id).style.backgroundColor = '#238EE1';

    } else {
      player2 = 'o';
      outputArray.push([currentType.id, player2]);
      document.getElementById(currentType.id).innerHTML = player2;
      document.getElementById(currentType.id).style.backgroundColor = '#FF1010';
    }


    chance++;
  }


  function checkIsWinner(currentObject, currentType) {

    winningCombinations = [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [3, 6, 9],
      [1, 5, 9],
      [3, 5, 7]
    ];

    if (chance == 2) {
      array1 = outputArray[0][0];
      array2 = outputArray[0][1];
      console.log("array1=" + array1 + " array2=" + array2)
    }

    if (chance == 3) {
      array3 = outputArray[1][0];
      array4 = outputArray[1][1];

      console.log("array3 = " + array3 + "  array4 = " + array4);
    }

    if (chance == 4) {
      array5 = outputArray[2][0];
      array6 = outputArray[2][1];

      console.log("array5 = " + array5 + "  array6 = " + array6);
    }

    if (chance == 5) {
      array7 = outputArray[3][0];
      array8 = outputArray[3][1];

      console.log("array7 = " + array7 + "  array8 = " + array8);
    }

    if (chance == 6) {
      array9 = outputArray[4][0];
      array10 = outputArray[4][1];

      console.log("array9 =" + array9 + "  array10 = " + array10);
    }

    if (chance == 7) {
      array11 = outputArray[5][0];
      array12 = outputArray[5][1];

      console.log("array11 =" + array11 + "  array12 = " + array12);
    }

    if (chance == 8) {
      array13 = outputArray[6][0];
      array14 = outputArray[6][1];
      console.log("array13 =" + array13 + "  array14 = " + array14);
    }

    if (chance == 9) {
      array15 = outputArray[7][0];
      array16 = outputArray[7][1];
      console.log("array15 =" + array15 + "  array16 = " + array16);
    }

    if (chance == 10) {
      array17 = outputArray[8][0];
      array18 = outputArray[8][1];
      console.log("array17 = " + array17 + "  array18 = " + array18);
    }



    for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {

      // console.log("array[row]="+outputArray[row]);
      answer1 = winningCombinations[row][0];
      answer2 = winningCombinations[row][1];
      answer3 = winningCombinations[row][2];


      if (((array1 == answer1 || array1 == answer2 || array1 == answer3) && (array5 == answer1 ||
          array5 == answer2 || array5 == answer3) && (array9 == answer1 || array9 == answer2 ||
          array9 == answer3))) {

        console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }

      if ((array1 == answer1 || array1 == answer2 || array1 == answer3) && (array5 == answer1 ||
          array5 == answer2 || array5 == answer3) && (array13 == answer1 || array13 == answer2 || array13 == answer3)) {
        isWinner = true;
        console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
        break;
      }
      if ((array1 == answer1 || array1 == answer2 || array1 == answer3) && (array5 == answer1 ||
          array5 == answer2 || array5 == answer3) && (array17 == answer1 ||
          array17 == answer2 || array17 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }

      if ((array1 == answer1 || array1 == answer2 || array1 == answer3) && (array9 == answer1 ||
          array9 == answer2 || array9 == answer3) && (array13 == answer1 || array13 == answer2 || array13 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }
      if ((array1 == answer1 || array1 == answer2 || array1 == answer3) && (array9 == answer1 ||
          array9 == answer2 || array9 == answer3) && (array17 == answer1 || array17 == answer2 ||
          array17 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }
      if ((array9 == answer1 || array9 == answer2 || array9 == answer3) && (array5 == answer1 ||
          array5 == answer2 || array5 == answer3) && (array13 == answer1 || array13 == answer2 || array13 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }
      if ((array9 == answer1 || array9 == answer2 || array9 == answer3) && (array5 == answer1 ||
          array5 == answer2 || array5 == answer3) && (array17 == answer1 || array17 == answer2 || array17 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }
      if ((array9 == answer1 || array9 == answer2 || array9 == answer3) && (array13 == answer1 ||
          array13 == answer2 || array13 == answer3) &&
        (array17 == answer1 || array17 == answer2 || array17 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }

      if ((array1 == answer1 || array1 == answer2 || array1 == answer3) && (array13 == answer1 ||
          array13 == answer2 || array13 == answer3) && (array17 == answer1 || array17 == answer2 ||
          array17 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
        winner = true;
        break;

      }
      if ((array13 == answer1 || array13 == answer2 || array13 == answer3) && (array5 == answer1 ||
          array5 == answer2 || array5 == answer3) && (array17 == answer1 || array17 == answer2 ||
          array17 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 1 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }

      if ((array3 == answer1 || array3 == answer2 || array3 == answer3) && (array7 == answer1 ||
          array7 == answer2 || array7 == answer3) && (array11 == answer1 || array11 == answer2 || array11 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 2 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }
      if ((array3 == answer1 || array3 == answer2 || array3 == answer3) && (array7 == answer1 ||
          array7 == answer2 || array7 == answer3) && (array15 == answer1 || array15 == answer2 || array15 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 2 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }

      if ((array3 == answer1 || array3 == answer2 || array3 == answer3) && (array15 == answer1 ||
          array15 == answer2 || array15 == answer3) && (array11 == answer1 || array11 == answer2 || array11 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 2 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }
      if ((array15 == answer1 || array15 == answer2 || array15 == answer3) && (array7 == answer1 ||
          array7 == answer2 || array7 == answer3) && (array11 == answer1 || array11 == answer2 || array11 == answer3)) {
        console.log("player 2 is the Winner");
        isWinner = true;
        break;

      }

    }


    tie--;
    if (tie <= 1) {
      console.log("Its a tie. Game Over !");
      checkTie = true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "exit from the program"? If this script is executed in a browser (let's say Chrome), do you want to close the browser window or tab?

Comment: What do you mean by `System.exit[0]`? There is nothing like that in javascript, as much as I know (at least, in the browser..)

Comment: Javascript is executed 'on demand', so there is no exit, or close of javascript code in a browser. You would need to reset your variables to re-run the game if the user wants to  play again, or remove the DOM elements from the page.

Comment: @Mosh Feu ..  System.exit[0] is a piece of code in java to exit / stop from running the program

Comment: @ Steve Padmore... here i have not used or created any dom  element to display so is there no other scope of exiting or stopping the game from execution.

Comment: @java_jazz but JavaScript, despite the name, has nothing to do with Java, and System.exit[0] doesn't exist in JavaScript. By the way, are you running the game in a web browser?

Comment: @java_jazz, the buttons you have dynamically created for the game are the DOM elements - you can't play tic-tac-toe without a visual display.

Comment: Why jquery? Is Daniel answer is what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing in in-browser Javascript as "exit the program", other than closing the browser window or navigating to a new page.  You can't call Java functions in Javascript because the two languages have nothing to do with one another, other than a highly unfortunate branding decision back in the day.

You already have an `isWinner` boolean to keep track of whether the game is supposed to be over, but currently you're not doing anything with it:

```
buttonKey.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  selectMark(event, event.srcElement);
  checkIsWinner();
  if (isWinner == true || checkTie == true) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

`return false` from an event handler prevents the event from bubbling to parent elements, which is not at all what you want to do here.

One rather bare-bones solution would be to have that function check whether the game is over before doing anything:

```
buttonKey.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (isWinner == true || checkTie == true) {
    console.log("The game is already over, no more moves.")
  } else {
    selectMark(event, event.srcElement); // you might also want to check whether the button is already marked here, before letting the user re-set it; or remove the click handler from each button as it's used
    checkIsWinner();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the script in a web browser, you can try to use `window.close()`, which closes the current browser window (or the current tab if the window has more than two tabs).

But be careful:

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened
>   by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not
>   opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the
>   console: `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script`.

See MDN web docs at [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close).

Instead, if you want to re-run the game or show a final screen that states that the game is over, consider modifying your DOM elements in the page, as closing the window/tab is not the best solution in this case.